# Start Windows Application from command Line

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, modern-ui

I'm trying to start a Windows Application from the command Line without success:

The application details are:

```
Name                   : SIBSFPS.MBWAY
PackageFullName        : SIBSFPS.MBWAY_1.6.0.12_neutral__fn0s81njkh37g
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SIBSFPS.MBWAY_1.6.0.12_neutral__fn0s81njkh88g
PackageFamilyName      : SIBSFPS.MBWAY_fn0s81njkh88g
```

I've tried :

```
explorer.exe shell:"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SIBSFPS.MBWAY_1.6.0.12_neutral__fn0s81njkh88g\SIBS.MBWAY.Windows.Windows.exe" -ServerName:App.AppX4jm6kxt8hhb5fqx4a2k6vtcbg46h8384.mca
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SIBSFPS.MBWAY_1.6.0.12_neutral__fn0s81njkh37g\SIBS.MBWAY.Windows.Windows.exe" -ServerName:App.AppX4jm6kxt8hhb5fqx4a2k6vtcbg46h8384.mca
```

but no luck, how can I do this?

Comment: Why does a UWP application have an executable extension?  Something doesn't add up.

Comment: [An ampersand `&` in front](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) tells Powershell to start the application   like `& C:\my\folder\program.exe`

Comment: "start SIBSFPS.MBWAY:" may work

Comment: Tks but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Window store apps are started via URLs not via the exe file. This is how you also open web sites.

The below command is a batch file that list all URL schemes on your computer including internet one. They are known as *protocol handlers*.

Because it sorts it, it takes several minutes to run.

```
@For /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%A in ('reg query HKCR /f "URL:*" /s /d ^| findstr /c:"URL:" ^| findstr /v /c:"URL: " ^| Sort') Do @Echo %%A %%B
pause
```

---

On my computer with no store apps but the ones that comes with Windows this is the list that took over 5 minutes.

```
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:armodelviewing  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Available Networks Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:bingweather  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:calculator  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:com.gotrust.cdfapp  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:com.microsoft.3dviewer  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Devices Flow Connectable Devices Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Devices Flow Display Topology Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:dlna-playsingle Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:dropbox-oem  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:evernote  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-events-share  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-api  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-api20131028  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-api20140131  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-api20140301  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-api20140430  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-diode  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-group-thread  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-neue  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-platform  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-platform-20150128  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-platform-20150218  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-platform-20150305  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-platform-20150714  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-public  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-share  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-share-api  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-messenger-voip  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fb-page-messages  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fbmessenger  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:feedback-hub  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:fiddlerapp  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:File Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:File Transfer Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:File Transfer Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:http  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:https  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol with Privacy  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:insiderhub  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:LDAP Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:LDAP Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:mailto  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:messenger  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft-edge  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.camera  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.camera.picker  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.crop  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.picker  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.videoedit  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoftmusic  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoftvideo  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:MK Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:mms Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:mms Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-aad-brokerplugin  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-actioncenter  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-appinstaller  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-apprep  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-calculator  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-clock  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-contact-support  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-cortana2  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-cxh  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-default-location  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-device-enrollment  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-drive-to  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-eyecontrolspeech  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-gamebarservices  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-gamingoverlay  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-get-started  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-getoffice  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-holographicfirstrun  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-inputapp  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-insights  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-ipmessaging  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-meetnowflyout  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-msdt  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-officeapp  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-officecmd  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-oobenetwork  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-paint  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-penworkspace  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-people  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-phone  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-photos  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-print-addprinter  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-print-printjobs  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-quick-assist  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-retaildemo-launchbioenrollment  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-retaildemo-launchstart  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-screenclip  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-screensketch  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-search  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-airplanemode  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-bluetooth  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-cellular  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-emailandaccounts  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-language  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-location  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-lock  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-mobilehotspot  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-notifications  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-power  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-privacy  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-proximity  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-screenrotation  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-wifi  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-workplace  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-sttoverlay  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-taskswitcher  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-unistore-email  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-voip-call  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-voip-video  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-walk-to  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-wcrv  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-windows-search  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-windows-store  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-windows-store2  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-wpc  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-wpdrmv  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-xgpueject  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnweather  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:om.facebook.317180b0bb486  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:onenote  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:onenote-cmd  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:outlookaccounts  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:outlookcal  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:outlookmail  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Play Single DLNA Item Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:pw.gregoauth2  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:read  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:RES Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:RLogin Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:rsgcribbagedeluxe  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:rsgheartsdeluxe  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:rsgsimplemahjong  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:rsgsimplesolitaire  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:rsgsimplespider  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:rtkuwp  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:skype  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:skypewin  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:spotify  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:tbauth  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:tel  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Telnet Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:TN3270 Protocol  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Virtual Touchpad  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:vscode  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:windows-feedback  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:windows.tbauth  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:windowsdefender  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbls  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-arena  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-captures  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-friendfinder  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-gamehub  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-lfg  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-network  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-profile  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-settings  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-store  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-tcui  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xboxgames  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xboxliveapp-1297287741  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xboxmusic  
(Default)    REG_SZ    URL:zune
```

To use them in Run dialog or a shortcut type (eg for Zune)  `zune:\\`

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually inside the command line you want to go to the correct directory and the run it

`C:
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SIBSFPS.MBWAY_1.6.0.12_neutral__fn0s81njkh88g\"
SIBS.MBWAY.Windows.Windows.exe -ServerName:App.AppX4jm6kxt8hhb5fqx4a2k6vtcbg46h8384.mca`

Note that the above are 3 separate lines, you need to hit enter after each one to run it.

I personally suggest using a batch file instead. same commands as above for the first 2 lines, but the 3rd line should have "start " at the begining

Comment: How can one get that -ServerName?

Comment: I got mine using process hacker

Comment: @Biswa the servername I included is the one provided by the person who asked the question. Your own individual servername depends on how you configured your server.